# How does shyvana's q proc on-hit item effects

Tags: league-of-legends

```
Twin Bite - Shyvana strikes twice on her next attack.

Dragon Form: Twin Bite cleaves all units in front Shyvana.
Shyvana strikes twice on her next attack, dealing (+0.8/0.85/0.9/0.95/1.0) physical  
damage on the second attack. 
The bonus damage is equal to 80/85/90/95/100% of Shyvana's Attack Damage.`

Dragon Form: Twin Bite cleaves all units in front Shyvana.
Cost
No Cost
Range
0
```

does this mean, Wit's End or other on-hit items will proc twice?

To Mind jumps:
Black Cleaver
Wit's End
Executioners Calling
BotRK

and the list goes on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Most of them, including your own list, will proc twice.** And when in dragon form, they will even proc twice **on each target hit by Twin Bite**.

Notable exceptions are on-hit effects with an internal cooldown, such as [Spellblade](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spellblade#Spellblade) (e.g. Sheen, Lich Bane).

See: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shyvana/Ability_Details